# Add column in a multindex panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index data frame and a dictionary. Some keys of this dictionary and some values of the first subcolumn coincide. I want to add a new column with the values of my dictionary In accordance with the query_name values.

Here my dataframe

```
                                          S_genus
query_name                                       
GCA_000237975.1 g__Sulfobacillus_A          118.0
GCA_000307585.2 g__Thermoanaerobacterium    118.0
                g__Thermoanaerobacter         1.0
                g__Ruminiclostridium_F        1.0
GCA_000404785.1 g__Cloacimonetes-1            1.0
...                                           ...
GCF_900141705.1 g__Fibrobacter              116.0
GCF_900142435.1 g__Thermocrinis_A           113.0
GCF_900175965.1 g__Rubrobacter              116.0
GCF_900176285.1 g__Desulfacinum             118.0
GCF_900215515.1 g__Persephonella            118.0
```

and here my dictionary

acc2genus

```
 'GCF_001658645.1': 'g__Staphylococcus',
 'GCF_900117665.1': 'g__Acinetobacter',
 'GCF_000652055.1': 'g__Mycobacterium',
 'GCF_003037025.1': 'g__Klebsiella',
 'GCF_002138225.1': 'g__Acinetobacter',
 'GCF_001186785.1': 'g__Vibrio',
 'GCF_001671475.1': 'g__Mesorhizobium',
 'GCF_000153745.1': 'g__Amylibacter_A',
 'GCF_002814015.1': 'g__Klebsiella',
```

I have tried things like that:

```
rdf["S_genus", "nueva"] = rdf["S_genus"].apply(lambda x: acc2genus[x])
```

I have tried many times and I got errors or I lost the third subcolumn (the numbers).

Anyone could help me?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without that everyone trying to help you is wasting his time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the MultiIndex to a DataFrame with `to_frame`, select the first level by its label (`query_name`), and use the dictionary to translate each value via a list comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

# example data frame, simplified
rdf = pd.DataFrame({'S_genus': [118.0, 118.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, 
                   index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                              [('GCA_000237975.1', 'g__Sulfobacillus_A'), 
                               ('GCA_000307585.2', 'g__Thermoanaerobacterium'), 
                               ('GCA_000307585.2', 'g__Thermoanaerobacter'), 
                               ('GCA_000307585.2', 'g__Ruminiclostridium_F ')]))
rdf.index.names = ['query_name', '']

# example dictionary, simplified
acc2genus = dict({'GCA_000237975.1': 'Sulfo', 
                  'GCA_000307585.2': 'Thermo'})

# new column: values from first index level translated via dictionary
rdf['nueva'] = [acc2genus[rdf.index.to_frame()['query_name'].values[i]] 
                for i in range(len(rdf))]
rdf
```

```
                                              S_genus   nueva
query_name          
GCA_000237975.1     g__Sulfobacillus_A        118.0     Sulfo
GCA_000307585.2     g__Thermoanaerobacterium  118.0     Thermo
                    g__Thermoanaerobacter       1.0     Thermo
                    g__Ruminiclostridium_F      1.0     Thermo
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I wanted. That works with my data

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.